# Tabulator V5.0.10 is logging stuff in console instead of firing expected callbacks

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm facing a weird issue while using Tabulator.
I was using Tabulator **V5.0.7** and everything was working fine except some callbacks, which wasn't fired at all and no errors was popping up in console.
So, I decided to open a question here, but before doing that I said "Oh well, lets first ensure no updates has been released on the package", and actually there were, so I upgraded the code to **V5.0.10**.

You have the js Table init here:

```js
var Tabella = new Tabulator("#tabella-lotti-aperti", {
  data:[],
  layout: "fitColumns",
  pagination: "local",
  responsiveLayout: "collapse",
  movableRows: true,
  columns: [
    { title: "Nome lotto", field: "Nome", headerFilter: true },
    { title: "Codice lotto", field: "Codice", headerFilter: true },
    { title: "Data d'apertura", field: "AperturaStr", headerFilter: true },
    { title: "Avanzamento", field: "Avanzamento", formatter: "progress", formatterParams: { color: "darkorange", legend: ValoreProgress } },
    { title: `<i class="fas fa-angle-double-up"></i>`, headerSort: false, field: "Priorita", hozAlign: "center", headerHozAlign: "center", width: 50, editor: "number",
       cellEdited: function (cell) { 
         console.log("EDITED")
       }
    },
    { title: `<i class="fas fa-search"></i>`, headerSort: false, formatter: IconaDettaglio, width: 25, hozAlign: "center", headerHozAlign: "center",
       cellClick: function (e, cell) {
         console.log("CLICK")
       }
    }
  ],
  rowMoved: function (row) {
    console.log("MOVED")
  }
})
```

Of course problem is not solved, but instead of getting nothing now Tabulator.js is logging stuff to console on those events that are not being called.
In my sample reported above the cellClick is working fine, instead, the cellEdited is never called and instead I can see the following line in the console:
[image]
[image]

RowMoved also is not being fired, and this one is not logging anything or rising any exceptions, I mean... it's just doing nothing at all.
I'm following the documentation at http://tabulator.info/docs/5.0 while building up the table, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I thought that modules could matter, but I'm pretty sure isn't that cause I already tried with esm import doing the following (always version 5.0.10) but nothing changed.

```js
import { TabulatorFull as Tabulator } from '../scripts/produzione/libraries/tabulator_esm.js'
```

Did you guys have any idea on this?
I can't get the point on the issue.

Comment: In v5.0, table event callbacks have now been replaced with an event subscription model. The callbacks that have changed to events are in the upgrade guide: http://tabulator.info/docs/5.0/upgrade#callbacks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tim.
As reported in the comment callbacks are now handled by an event subscription model.

More details available here [Tabulator callbacks documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.0/upgrade#callbacks)

Comment: Hi @Hele, I need to walk back my comment.  Looks like this is indeed a bug.  `cellEdited` is not being called on cell callback.  I have opened an issue: https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/3536

Comment: Ok Tim, i didn't notice that cause i was working on backend, i only tried the RowMoved callback wich was working as expected, let's see what devs will say about this issue.

Comment: These issues should now have been resolved in the latest patch releases